# Application .NetCore hosted in HTTPS don`t call HTTP Rest

Tags: http, asp.net-core, https, .net-core

I Have a application AspNetCore 2.2 hosted in a server with SSL Certification (HTTPS) and i need consuming a Rest Service that is in other server don`t SSL Certification (HTTP).

The error return is:

> "One or more errors occurred. (A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected component did not respond correctly \ r \ n after a period
>   of time or the established connection failed \ r \ nbecause the
>   connected host did not respond)"

My call in my ServiceRepository(HTTPS) is:

```
public ServiceRepository()
{
    Client = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://###.##.##.##:####/")
    };
}
```

http://###.##.##.##:####/ is my path for my Rest
But this don`t work!
Please i need this connection for consuming my Rest Service

Comment: Check firewall?

Comment: @Tseng Firewall of Rest (HTTP) or of Application (HTTPS) ?

Comment: Either. What you are getting is a timeout message, which you get when packet are dropped or the service is not reachable (docker services that are not in a common network or can call out?) To little information for more

Comment: @Tseng the call is ok in PostMan for example, in PostMan i call the rest and work. in application don`t work, sorry my english